# Change this react class component into react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, backend

I am watching a tutorial of MERN Stack here in this video [MERN](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7CqJlxBYj-M).
At the part of 1:41:16 - 1:47:01
I am trying to convert everything into react hooks and everything went well not until for the part of `exercise-list component`

So here is my code when I converted it into react-hook component.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'

const Exercise = item => {
    <tr>
        <td>{item.exercise.username} </td>
        <td>{item.exercise.description} </td>
        <td>{item.exercise.duration} </td>
        <td>{item.exercise.date.substring(0,10)} </td>
        <td><Link to={"/edit/" + item.exercise._id}> Edit</Link> | 
        <a href="#" onClick={e => {item.handledeleteExercise(item.exercise._id)}}> delete </a>
        
        </td>

    </tr>
}

function Exercises_List(props) {

    const [deleteExercise,setdeleteExercise] = useState()

    const [exercises,setexercises] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:4500/exercises/')
            .then(res => {
                setexercises([...exercises,res.data])
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    },[])

    const handledeleteExercise = (id) => {
        axios.delete('http://localhost:4500/exercises'+id)
            .then(res => console.log(res.data));
        const filtered = exercises.filter((el) => el._id !== id)
        setexercises(filtered)
    }

    const exerciseList = () => {
        return exercises.map(currentexercise => {
            return <Exercise 
                exercise={currentexercise} 
                handledeleteExercise={e => handledeleteExercise(e)}
                key={currentexercise._id}></Exercise>
        })
    }

  
    return (
  
        <div>
            <h3> Logged Exercises</h3>
            <table className="table">
                <thead className="thead-light">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Username </th>
                        <th>Description </th>
                        <th>Duration </th>
                        <th>Date </th>
                        <th>Actions </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {exerciseList()}
                </tbody>
            </table>


        </div>
  
        )
}

export default Exercises_List
```

the only thing that confuses me here is `const [deleteExercise,setdeleteExercise] = useState()` 
As you see in the video of 1:41:22 .. I am very confused of how should I with deleteExercise to convert it in react-hooks.. I tried it something like this

````
deleteExercise = e => {
 ....
}
``` But I know that is out of the rules in react hooks...Another thing I look at here is this part of
````

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:4500/exercises/')
        .then(res => {
            setexercises({...exercises:res.data})
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
},[])
```

```
once I show this in my output
```

```
   {exerciseList()}
```

It gives me an error like this `TypeError: exercises.map is not a function`

I think I miss an idea here...I am also confused at the part of `edit-exercises.component` wherein it passing the `props.match.params.id` at part of 1:43:32..

Guys I am dying..I badly want to make simple full-stack-website but I just can't lol...the tutorials and my documentation learning are confusing specially the updates and documentation.

I cannot explain it all I am briefly sorry about that...What I want to just resolve here is the converting it into react-hooks since react class component is not really useful in my nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is failing because of this:

```js
setexercises({...exercises:res.data})
```

That statement stores *an object* in the `exercises` variable, and objects do not have a `map` method.

(Actually, I think that statement isn't valid syntax: you can't place three dots before a property name that also has a value. You could do this: `({ ...res.data })` or this `({ exercises: res.data })` -- although both will still break the same way because both store *an object* instead of an array. But these are at least valid ES6 syntax.)

I suspect the larger problem is that you're not thinking about your data correctly.

- you've got a list of exercises
- you want to be able to add and remove items on that list

It seems clear that you only need *one* array. That single array is what you should store using React's `useState` hook:

```js
let [ exercises, setExercises ] = React.useState([])
```

Thus: `exercises` is the list (an array with a `map` method), and `setExercises` lets you completely overwrite that array. Pay attention to that last piece: *the only tool* provided by the useState hook is a tool that *clobbers the whole list*. That means your "add" and "remove" operations must accomplish their tasks using just that tool.

So, you have to finish the implementation of this function:

```js
function addExercise( newExercise ) {
  /*
    STEP 1: calculate fresh array that contains
    all the current exercises plus newExercise.
  */
  let newList = [/* TODO */]

  /*
    STEP 2: overwrite current list using the
    only tool provided by useState. This updates
    the data *and* immediately re-renders the
    component with the new data.
  */
  setExercises(newList)
}
```

The same thinking applies to removing an exercise from the list:

```js
function removeExercise( exerciseToRemove ) {
  /*
    STEP 1: calculate fresh array that contains
    all the current exercises minus exerciseToRemove.
  */
  let newList = [/* TODO */]

  /*
    STEP 2: overwrite current list using the
    only tool provided by useState.
  */
  setExercises(newList)
}
```

That same tool is also how you update the list when your API call returns:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('http://localhost:4500/exercises/')
  // this assumes that res.data is an array
  .then(res => setExercises(res.data))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
}, [])
```

---

Also: your Exercises component probably doesn't parse. The curly braces that wrap the body need to be parentheses, or you need a `return` statement inside the body:

```
// bad!
const MyComp = props => { <div> thing </div> }

// good
const MyComp = props => ( <div> thing </div> )

// also good
const MyComp = props => { return (<div> thing </div>) }
```

Comment: Oh thank god the only thing I am wrong is the exercises component part..I didn't notice it T_T thank you very much.

Comment: but now I am troubling with edit and delete hahah